# are there any quad isolation exercises besides a leg extension machine

Tags: quads, isolation

I can only find one true quad isolation exercise and that's the leg extension exercise. My issue is I have a glute medius strain, which only seems to effect when I'm squatting, whether that's one leg or both. I can only squat maybe 20 degrees at most before I feel mild tension, and naturally the more I go the worst it feels up to 90 degrees. Since it can take 4-6 weeks for a strain, I'd like to not lose all my progress, as I seem to feel fine doing RDL's. I also feel fine doing standing abduction machines and the like. It's the "driving through the heel" maneuver from knee flexion that seems to cause a lot of pain. So I'm wondering if all I have available to me is leg extension machine for the next 6 weeks to continue making progress?

Comment: Leg press is a no bueno as well?

Comment: I thought about that.. unfortunately I workout in my garage. I have everything from barbells, dumbbells, resistance bands, pulley towers, pullup bars, a plyometric box, etc but I don't own any machines.

Comment: Split squats and lunges are out too?

Comment: I've had success performing Sissy Squats while avoiding glute activation. It's not a "driving through the heel" feeling as much as through the balls of your feet. If you haven't tried them before or in a while, you'll definitely feel your quads burn quickly

Comment: @DeeV Yes, any unilateral squat-type movement too such as lunges and split squats,

Comment: @Jros Thanks, do you do them with TRX bands, off a bench, etc?

Comment: @AceCabbie If you want to use a TRX band or barbell for balance to begin, thats what i usually start with from flat ground, then you can increase the deficit by standing on a plate or bench and dipping knees further. Its one of those movements where being controlled is 90% of it, while getting depth is the rest